# getField not displaying results

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to display points from a user row on a profile page.  I try using the following

```
<?php echo $profile->getField('points');?>
```

to pull up the field that holds a users points but nothing is displaying for the user I am testing it with. I am testing it logged in as the user who has 16 points set, but nothing will show, any ideas whats wrong ? If instead of ('points') I put ('username') or ('name') it will display those fields, but not points. Thanks for any assistance! [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what it could be. Have you tried using error_reporting(E_ALL); above your script?  Perhaps use an or die().mysql_error(); to find out more..Also why is points Char and not say varchar or int?

Comment: still no errors coming back on my end.  I did change the CHAR to VARCHAR now, but still not working! Thanks for the assistance though mate !